# Formula for multiline cell input to output multiline cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Rough Outline:**
I am looking for a formula to match up values from a list that can contain single line cells and multiline cells to a table with single values = single values. (Not sure if this properly explains my need)

**Requirements:**
Ideally this will work on Excel Online, without VBA support as I believe UDFs are disabled.

**Breakdown:**
I have a list of parts. Each part is assigned a code number in a separate table (on separate sheet)
I have a formula to check if the part exists in this table and output the code number, but this only works for single line entries. Due to how we are keeping record, some entries will have multiple parts, and thus, multiple lines in a cell.

**Example:**
I would like my main sheet to have parts recorded, and in the next cell a formula to output their code numbers.
So, assuming Part A = Code 1, Part B = Code 2, Part C = Code 3 (*As defined in another table*)

```
A1 = Part A          | B1 = Code 1  

A2 = Part A          | B2 = Code 1
     Part C          |      Code 3  

A3 = Part B          | B3 = Code 2
```

and so forth. Cells with multiple outputs (i.e. B2) will be in the same cell as a multiline.

[Excel Multiline Expectaions Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbrO0.jpg)

Editted the example for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTERXML to split and return the array to XLOOKUP that returns the return array to TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,XLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),E:E,F:F,"",0))
```

Change both the `CHAR(10)` to what ever the delimiter is between the inputs.  You screen shot shows the return, but your verbiage shows `&`  Change to what you need/want.

Make sure your wrap text is set to true on the output cells.

[image]

Comment: Hello Scott, I can see it working in your picture but when I place it into my example I receive the error: Error in Value (A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type).
I have my cells formatted as General, but I also tried Text and Number to no effect.
Also, I do want the CHAR(10) as the delimiter, thanks. The & was just to show multiple values in the cell.

Comment: Where are you using it? It works in office 365 excel.

Comment: Also note that FILTERXML only works on Windows computers, not on Mac. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7

Comment: I couldn't find documentation, but it doesn't work on Chromebook either (just checked)

Comment: I believe it to be Office 365. I can access the book through office.com and work on it through a web browser.

Comment: I just tried typing =FILTER and =FILTERXML does not show as a suggested function

Comment: You can translate any formula [here](https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/).